# Why isn't my background clipping to the text like it's supposed to?

Tags: css, background

I'm new to CSS so I don't know a whole lot, but I'm trying to make my header text a gradient. I've made the background gradient, made the text transparent, and still, the background just will not clip to the text like it's supposed to. I can't find anyone else with this problem. *(originally my background was a gradient, but for simplicity I changed it to red)*

```
h1 {
    color: transparent;
    background-clip: text;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: background-clip AFTER background

Comment: ^ The `background` property sets all `background-x` properties in one declaration. Put the `background-clip` after your `background` declaration or put your `background-clip` value within the `background` declaration. Or change `background` to `background-color`, since you're only setting one property with it.

Comment: alright that makes sense, thank you